# How to read the actual Content value (html source) from Content Editor webpart

Tags: pnp-powershell, sharepoint-server

I want to read the actual Content value (html source) from Content Editor web part using powershell or pnp powershell. Also, i want to read the web part properties PartOrder,TypeName.

```
<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[<p>​<br/></p>Testing the content editor<br/><br/>]]></Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
$completeUrl="http://sp:"
$SPweb = Get-SPWeb($completeUrl)

$wpMngr = $SPweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SitePages/testWebPart.aspx",[System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared); #you could change the page
foreach($wp in $wpMngr.WebParts)
{ 
Write-Host "TypeName" $wp
Write-Host "content" $wp.ContentLink                        
Write-Host "PartOrder" $wp.PartOrder
Write-Host "------------"
}
$SPweb.Dispose()
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Content link able to read.. But i want to read the content of the content editor web part((html source)

Comment: CDATA i want to add